# Is the t-test really robust to shape of distribution?

Tags: normal-distribution, t-test, robust

Can I use the t-test to compare means between groups (N=300) if data is not normally distributed?

Comment: It depends. In some cases, n=3 suffices even though the distribution is non-normal. In other cases n=3000 isn't enough...

Comment: See any of these (only a sampling of many): [1](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/56194/is-it-possible-to-use-a-two-sample-t-test-here) [2](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/53053/mann-whitney-or-two-tailed-t-test) [3](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/54913/t-test-equivalent-for-samples-given-a-distribution-of-unknown-form) [4](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/52047/when-sample-size-is-small-and-distribution-is-not-normal-should-i-use-wilcoxon-o) [5](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/49465/mann-whitney-for-non-normal-distributions-with-n20)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Glen. This is really helpful. Did not see the other posts before ...